# Visual Studio doesnt "redirect" properly

Tags: visual-studio

I'm having a problem with Visual Studio. Until yesterday, when I pressed Ctrl + the left button of my mouse, it redirected to the class, etc.

However, this behavior has changed. For example, in the image below, when I try to go to the "Administrador" class, it doesn't do anything. This happens with all classes.

[image: Visual Studio Class Screenshot]

Comment: I have edited your question. Please review it and add any additional relevant details.

Comment: The problem is well explained. I don't know which other details do you want.